# Making a button to move an element from one html page to another html page

Tags: html, data-transfer

I wanted to take an image from one HTML file and when the user clicks a button, that image moves to a standard cell of a different HTML file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why do you need to move elements between pages? My answer is probably not the best solution to your problem, however, it is what you asked for.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you mean by "standard cell". Do you mean a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

To move an element between pages, if both pages are on the same domain, you can get the HTML of the element, put it in localStorage, then delete the element. On the other page, poll the localStorage for changes, the parse the element and use it in the DOM.

I wrote a set of functions to do that. On the sending page use this code. Call the function `moveElement` with the element you want to move to the other page.

```js
const page="Your Page Name";

function moveElement(element){
  const prefix="_elementmover_"+page+"_";
  localStorage.setItem(prefix+"htmlToMove",element.outerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem(prefix+"changedHtmlToMove",localStorage.getItem(prefix+"changedHtmlToMove")*1+1);
  image.remove()
}
```

On the receiving page, use this code. The function `receivedElement` will be called wth the element.

```js
const page="Your Page Name";

function receivedElement(element){
  // Do whatever you want with the element here.
}

(()=>{
  const prefix="_elementmover_"+page+"_";
  let getChangeNum=()=>localStorage.getItem(prefix+"changedHtmlToMove")*1;
  let oldChangeNum=getChangeNum();
  let checkForChanges=()=>{
  let newChangeNum=getChangeNum();
  if(oldChangeNum!=newChangeNum){
    let element=new DOMParser().parseFromString(localStorage.getItem(prefix+"htmlToMove"),"text/html").querySelector("html>body>*");
    receivedElement(element)
  }
  oldChangeNum=newChangeNum
  setTimeout(checkForChanges,100);
}
checkForChanges();
})();
```

Please note that the `page` variable should be unique on each set of pages it is on, but both pages must have the same value for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I change whatever is in red to suit my project.

Comment: Change `const page="Your Page Name";` and `// Do whatever you want with the element here.`